# GridVIew has one Databind on page_load and another when a button is click. When on second Databind if pagenumber click goes to 1st Databind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a GridView with Paging and Programatically Databind it on Page_Load. Also I have a search button that when clicked it databinds to a diferent sql command. If you click the search button and it retrieve more than one page and if you click on page 2 it retrieves the data of the first Databind(). How can I fix that using the GridView1.PageIndexChanging which is what I'm using for paging on the first Databind? Anyhelp would be very appreciated. Is it even posible?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="100">
 <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldEmployeeID" HeaderText="EmployeeID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldAbsentDate" HeaderText="AbsentDate" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldAbsentCode" HeaderText="AbsentCode" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldRuleViolationWarningType" HeaderText="Rule Violation Warning" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldRuleViolationIssueDate" HeaderText="Rule Violation Issue Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="fldLOAEndDate" HeaderText="LOA End Date" />
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

vb.net

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim SqlDataSource1 As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()
    SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1"
    Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1)
    SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "your connection string"
    'SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] WHERE [fldEmployeeID]=38"
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] ORDER BY [fldEmployeeID], [fldAbsentDate], [fldAbsentCode]"
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim SqlDataSource2 As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()
    SqlDataSource2.ID = "SqlDataSource2"
    Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource2)
    SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = "your connection string"
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] WHERE [fldAbsentDate] BETWEEN '7-03-2014' AND '8-21-2014' ORDER BY [fldAbsentDate]"
    'SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] ORDER BY [fldEmployeeID], [fldAbsentDate], [fldAbsentCode]";
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: When you click on a page number using gridview paging it triggers the page load event during postback. Which changes the SqlDataSource back to SqlDataSource1. You can check to see it's doing postback and tell it not to do anything other than databind()... but that's only if you don't intend on reverting back to SqlDataSource1 at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an invisible html label/textbox into your main form...

```
<asp:label runat="Server" ID="SDS2" visible="false" text="0" />
```

Page Load would look like the following, and would likely benefit from having the SDS2 added to it as well in an 'else' clause in the same IF statement.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If SDS2.Text = "0"
        Dim SqlDataSource1 As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()
        SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1"
        Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1)
        SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "your connection string"
        'SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] WHERE [fldEmployeeID]=38"
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] ORDER BY [fldEmployeeID],       [fldAbsentDate], [fldAbsentCode]"
        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1

        GridView1.DataBind()
    Else
        'Call the SDS2 stuff here
    End If
End Sub
```

And in your button click handler add this line to set it to use SDS2 instead.

```
SDS2.Text = "1"
```

Comment: Hey Zack it doesnt retrieve anything. is like the ViewGrid disappears

Comment: So, the initial gridview displays nothing at all when you load the page?

Comment: Other option is to have a hidden element in the webform(like a hidden label or textbox) and assign it a value used as a flag not to change the datasource to SqlDataSource1 during post back, and when you need it to revert back to SDS1 just reset the value of the label/textbox to the default value. I usually use "0" for false and "1" for true. Will edit answer with example of what I mean...

Comment: No It does not but If you run the whole code again it works. So what i did it was to create a flag using Session to know if the SqlDatasource2 has been Binded. So now it works. But i have the problem: If on SQLDataSource1 and click Page11 when click the button search the pagging stays as click on page 11. How do I restart the counter of the pagging

Comment: You can put a line in your button click to reset it. `GridView1.PageIndex = 0`